# Netsuite Invoice Pdf Show Amount Applied

Tags: pdf, netsuite, invoice

Problem:

I have advanced pdf enabled on invoices, and trying to show the amount credited or partially paid.

Researched:

I found out from Saved Search you can get ***Applying Transaction Fields...*** and select ***Applying Transaction : Amount*** and ***Applying Transaction : Type***,
and that's exactly what I need on the invoice.

But I don't know how to access those fields inside the template.

Tried:

```
    <tr class="totalrow">
    <td background-color="#ffffff" colspan="4">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="right"><b>${record.applyingtransaction.type}</b></td>
    <td align="right">${record.applyingtransaction.amount}</td>
    </tr>
```

It doesn't render them.

Answer (score 2):

You can print just the total amount paid using

```
${record.amountpaid}
```

You won't be able to show the payment type without making this information accessible to the template using a script.

Comment: I do know how to create scripts, but I have no idea where I can add the script in order to add more variables to the template.

Comment: I think you could use a user event beforeLoad script and check the context.type for `context.UserEventType.PRINT`